# How to convert integer to enum variant with matching discriminant value?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have an enum with two variants including discriminant values:

```rust
enum E {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
}
```

I can easily convert `E` into, say, an `i32` by doing:

```rust
fn f() {
    let e = E::A;
    let i = e as i32;
}
```

When trying the reverse I would expect the following to work:

```rust
fn g(i: i32) {
    let e: E = i.try_into().unwrap(); // E0277: the trait bound `E: std::convert::From<i32>` is not satisfied
}
```

What is the shortest / most idiomatic way to do this **without writing a separate `match` implementation** myself?

Comment: The language is missing this IMHO. You should write an issue.

Comment: The answer to the linked question suggest using the `num_derive` crate that includes this functionality.

Comment: Technicaly yes, but practically no. It's nice to know a 3rd party crate is available, but I'd like to do this without adding extra dependencies.

Comment: Then copy and paste the source code of the dependency into your project. Now you don't have to worry about any pesky dependencies.

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't think there is need to be sarcastic. My question was about the shortest way how I can implement this, adding the source of whole dependency surely won't help.

Comment: No sarcasm; if a dependency does what you want but you don’t want a dependency, you copy it and delete what isn’t used. There are other linked answers that you would likewise copy and paste and modify, there’s no difference.